# Calculation of time between an event in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to capture the time between an event. Then I have to use this value for another an event. 
my problem is that what is the unit of time_2 in my program. How I can use this value in if loop. I think this value is not a actual value.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module time_control( input clk  );
  reg [7:0] memory [0:15] ;
  integer k=0;

  realtime time_1 =0;
  realtime time_2 =0;

  always @ ( posedge clk)
  begin 

    time_2=time_1 ;
    time_1 = $realtime ;

     if( time_2 < 500) //Comparison Not working
     begin 
       memory[k] <=k;
       k         <=k+1 ;
     end     

  end
endmodule
```

In the programming part in the starts is not working. My question was that using the value of tine_2, i can fill the memory. whenever the value of time_2 is greater than 500 ns then it should not place the value of in the memory. i don't want to store the value of time.

This is for simulation only.

Comment: Are you looking for something synthesizable? Time variables are for simulation only. To be synthesizable you need to count clocks.

Comment: "I want to capture the time between an event." Here an event means a clock edge? Your comment asks "how i can use time value for an event". I do not know what you mean by 'event' in the second context. Please update the answer describing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is to store realtimes, or time diffs based on realtimes it needs to be of an appropriate type.

```
reg [7:0] memory [0:15] ;
```

Should be

```
realtime memory [0:15];
```

For comparison of times, use a time:

```
if( time_2 < 500) begin
```

becomes :

```
if( time_2 < 500ns ) begin
```

NB: the first version worked fine for me as the time units be default are often ’ns’, or specified as ’ns’ using `` `timescale ``.

Your example would become:

```
module time_control( input clk  );
  realtime memory [0:15] ;
  integer k=0;

  realtime time_1 =0;
  realtime time_2 =0;

  always @( posedge clk) begin 
    time_2 = time_1 ;
    time_1 = $realtime ;

    if( time_2 < 500ns ) begin 
      memory[k] <=k;
      k         <=k+1 ;
    end   
  end
endmodule
```